# Flutter Web - Google Chrome Marked Web-app as Dangerous

Tags: flutter, google-chrome

I'm having some trouble determining why Google Chrome is marking my Flutter Web-App as "Dangerous." When I enter my login password, even before hitting the login button, a popup appears:

[image]

On the left side of the URL, where the "lock" icon would normally be, then shows the text "Dangerous" in red.

[image]

Clicking on this text makes the following appear:

[image]

After a few searches, I found a [Google site](https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search) that can give you the status of a URL. I tried using this to help determine what may be wrong, but it doesn't provide any insight as to what my issue is. It looks like I should be able to check each of the pages individually, but this may be restricted, due to the fact that this is a web-app?

[image]

> Try to trick visitors into sharing personal info or downloading
> software

I do not get the issue if I enter just any password - these events are only triggered if I enter a password saved on my Google Account.

The only time that I have NOT received this message, was when I did a full clear of my browsing history. After visiting a few other sites and allowing google to save my password, which is the same I use on my site for testing, the issue reoccurred. I downloaded Firefox and repeated the process of logging into other sites, and the error didn't occur there. I also went as far as to test this on Edge and Opera, but no issues there either. All browsers show the certificate as Valid. The site shows as Secure on all browsers, except Chrome.

I am using Firebase Hosting, with Firebase Authentication, so my site *should* be secure. Maybe I am just missing something mandatory, such as requesting the user to allow cookies? Many sites I visit have this feature, which my web-app doesn't currently have. Or, maybe there is something else?

Obviously, this looks extremely bad, so I would like to fix this up as soon as possible. In advance, I would like to thank anyone for their input on this.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when my website with my custom domain worked as expected, but a test version of the same website on ....appspot.com (Google App Engine's domain) triggered this warning.

I remember I appealed this issue to Google, and it was resolved in 24 hours. The issue had nothing to do with the contents of my website.

Check the status of your site here:
https://transparencyreport.google.com/safe-browsing/search

Comment: Thank you for your response! I will absolutely give this a shot. However, I'm a little curious - you said the issue had nothing to do with the contents of your website. Would you mind sharing the reason they flagged your site then? Perhaps it was just merely a glitch in their algorithm?

Comment: My website at appspot.com is an identical copy of my website at the custom domain. Maybe their algorithm decided that my appspot.com version impersonated my "real" website.

Comment: Very interesting! By chance, do you remember where you went to dispute your page. I'm trying to look now, but mostly finding how to report content to them.

Comment: Try this: https://safebrowsing.google.com/safebrowsing/report_error/?hl=en

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing.  When I check out safe browsing by google it tells me my site is unsafe as follows:

Some pages on this site are unsafe
The site https://crefinancials-fecdb.web.app/auth contains harmful content, including pages that:

Try to trick visitors into sharing personal info or downloading software
Unsafe content might only appear on some pages of a website. Check the URL of the specific directory or webpage you want to visit for more detailed safety info.